# How to store user profile photo in list using Microsoft Flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-property, flow

I have requirement that I need to get current weeks birthday. The approach we are using is we have create a flow and it is recurring every day. It will go through each user in delve and check if any user's birthday match with today's date. If it matches, we add users's entry with details like user email, birthday message and user image.

I am able to put all other details in list except user image. I am having below output when I use "Get User Photo (V2)" action:

[image: Get user photo]

But when I add this out put in create item, it is storing junk data in my list.

[image: Create list item error]

My column type in list is single line of text. If I keep it to hyperlink or picture, the variable do not show up in the create item action.

Is there anything or any way I can store the user image in custom list? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you storing an imag in single line text? Output from get user photo is not even a picture url

Comment: I got your point. I have created separate column for content and it is multiple line of text. But how can I get content value and store in this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally able to get the photo from flow. I have updated my list and created new column picturecontent (multiple line of text). This is used to store `$content` data. My previous column is storing `$content-type` data.

I have used below expression in create item:

for content type:

```
body('Get_user_photo_(V2)')?['$content-type']
```

for content:

```
body('Get_user_photo_(V2)')?['$content']
```

[image: Flow user photo]

This stores the value in my list.

[image: flow user image 1]

I am able to generate image using below code:

```
<img src="data:content-type-value;content-value">
```

Comment: `I am able to generate image using below code:` Where do you use this code? In th column formatting? If so, could you post the full column formatting code?

Comment: I am showing an image in custom coding. So the image tag src will be made of two values we are storing in Title and Content columns.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me really good. Instead of saving in a list, I did it in a variable and it worked as well. Thanks for sharing.

My way was storing the values in two different variables, see examples below:
[image]

[image]

And then I passed each variables in an img tag:

```
<img src="data:varContentType;base64,varContent"/>
```

And it worked really well and the PDF export is showing my image.