# How to store user profile photo in list using Microsoft Flow? elaboration on solution

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-property, flow, microsoft-flow

original question that wont let me comment on or expand on...

[How to store user profile photo in list using Microsoft Flow?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/253337/how-to-store-user-profile-photo-in-list-using-microsoft-flow/253776#253776)

How did you get the code `<img src="data:content-type-value;content-value">` to work?

I am using this to pass the photo info from a SP list into a Ticker with spservices.

"PhotoContentType" gets $content-type passed to it and "Picture" gets the $content passed to it.

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "NewUsers",
    webURL: "/sites/CFFIntranet",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Created' /><FieldRef Name='Department' /><FieldRef Name='Location' /><FieldRef Name='Picture' /><FieldRef Name='PhotoContentType' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

    console.log(Status);
    console.log("GetListItems operation: " + xData.responseText);

    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {  

            var PhotoContentType = $(this).attr("ows_PhotoContentType");         
            var Picture = $(this).attr("ows_Picture");
            var Name = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
            var Created = $(this).attr("ows_Created");
            var Department = $(this).attr("ows_Department");
            var Location = $(this).attr("ows_Location");
            var fixedDate = convertDateSlashFormat(Created);


            var NewUL = "<li> <img src='data:"+PhotoContentType+";"+Picture+"'/>  "+Name+" "+Department+"</li>";                    
            $("#NewEmpTickerUL").append(NewUL);


            });
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found by changing:

`var NewUL = "<li> <img src='data:"+PhotoContentType+";"+Picture+"'/>  "+Name+" "+Department+"</li>";
$("#NewEmpTickerUL").append(NewUL);`

to:

`var NewUL = "<li> <img src='data:"+PhotoContentType+";base64,"+Picture+"'/>  "+Name+" "+Department+"</li>";
 $("#NewEmpTickerUL").append(NewUL);`

The picture will show correctly.